# how do i know what is the video resolution in elementary os juno

Tags: release-juno, ubuntu, elementary-project

[image]

[image: i know the video type but idk the video resolution]

here you can see there is no video resolution in the info page like ubuntu so if any one knows where i can find it your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install VLC you can open the video and then just `right click > codec information` will show you the video resolution and all the data you might want to know.

Comment: ty that was very helpful

Comment: No problem! I've created a [bug report](https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/713) as well so maybe you can see the resolution directly from the Properties tab in the future :)